# Adding Qt to a C-Socket program?

Tags: c++, c, qt, sockets, pthreads

I am working on a simple socket application written in C, which allows two members to communicate over the internet using basic command line prompt.

I would like to add a proper GUI to it, just to use a decent UI and not basic standard input/output.

Right now I am developing with Cygwin to use POSIX threads and sockets. Is there anyway to hook it up to Qt?

Comment: Well, using QT would require rewriting your program from C to C++...

Comment: @Shawn Why is that? I thought C++ is backwards compatible? It imagined I just had to embed my already existing C project in QT.

Comment: If you don't want to redesign your C program, one possible work-around would be to have your Qt GUI launch your C program as a sub-process (via the `QProcess` class) and read the sub-process's stdout and write to its stdin.  (i.e. it would act as a "wrapper" around the original program rather than including the original code directly)

Comment: There are quite a few similarities between the languages, but it's trivial to write C that follows that languages best practices that is invalid C++.

Comment: @ilmu011 While C and C++ share *some* syntax and functionality, they are by now (C11 vs C++17) *very* different languages and you can even find constructs that are valid in both but have completely different meaning. Yes, there is a C subset in C++, but it is getting smaller by the hour and you should *not* assume that just because something compiles with both a C and a C++ compiler, it will do the same thing. Two very different languages - period.

Comment: I have used both C and C++ for more than 25 years. Usually, compiling and porting a program from C to C++ is not hard at all. You should be able to move your C code to C++ and use Qt without too much hassle. Of course, with C++, you tend to use STL, smart pointers and so on, which makes your code easier to write and easier to maintain. But remember, keep it simple - simple is almost always good!

Answer (score 2):

As Shawn mentioned above, using Qt entails the use of an object-based language (probably C++ in your case). But there's another consideration -- Qt is a multi-platform framework; it can be thought of as a layer between your application and the OS it runs on. So, while the literal answer to your question is "yes," if you're going to use Qt for its UI abilities, you're better off (IMO) using its socket facility [QAbstractSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html) as well, rather than use the native (or Cygwin) socket API.